# Replacing the same string multiple times in a file with different input in C#

Tags: c#, text-files

I currently have a text file that has a couple of sentences that looks like this:

```
Hello. Your name is <name> and the username you have chosen is <username>. 
Your password is <password>. Your friend's username is <username> 
and their password is <password>.
```

What I first do is ask the user the following questions:

```
 public string questions(string sentences)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Your Name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter Your Username: ");
                string userName= Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter Your Password: ");
                string password= Console.ReadLine();
                string textFile = File.ReadAllText(sentences);
                textFile = textFile.Replace("<name>", name);
                textFile = textFile.Replace("<username>", userName);
                textFile = textFile.Replace("<password>", password);
                File.WriteAllText(sentences, textFile);
                return textFile;
        }
```

When the user inputs their name, it's not a problem because there is only one `<name>`, however, when it comes to the password and username, it's a problem. For example, when the user inputs the username, it replaces everything in the file that says `<username>` when I only want to replace the first `<username>`. What I would like this program to do is to read the file and every time it encounters `<name>`, `<password>`, or `<username>` to prompt the user to enter their name, password or username and replace only that placeholder, not all the placeholders with similar names.

Is there a way I can edit my current code to achieve this? I thought about numbering stuff in the text file like `<name1>` or `<username1>` but then this would only work with this particular text file. What if the text file contains an unknown amount of usernames or passwords?

Comment: Can you read the file line by line ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Yes, the file can be read line by line. It doesn't have to read the entire text file at once.

Comment: Umm, why are you trying to send the friend's password? That sounds like a bad idea. If you properly hash the passwords you shouldn't even be able to do that...

Comment: @user1429080 it's not for real passwords. You can replace `<password>` for anything. It was just a couple sentences that I thought of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

you can try Regex.Replace

```
var regex = new Regex("<username>");
textFile = regex.Replace(textFile, userName, 1);
```